# Xcode 11 CFLocaleCopyCurrent console error

Tags: xcode, xcode11

Just installed Xcode 11.0 beta (11M336w), and once running an empty app getting this console error:

> [general] CFLocaleCopyCurrent() failed to look up current locale via
>   'AppleLocale' and 'AppleLanguages' in user preferences; falling back
>   to locale identifier 'en_US' as the default. Consider checking Console
>   for sandbox violations from this process for reading from preferences,
>   or enabling CoreFoundation debug logging for more information. This
>   will only be logged once.

I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant, but worth mentioning that the empty app uses SwiftUI

Comment: It seems this may be why `Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: "US")` returns `nil`, when previously it returned `"United States"`. So, for me, this is an actual bug.

Comment: Filed bug with Apple

Comment: Reproduced without `SwiftUI`.

Comment: Does this also happen when building to a physical device?

Answer (score 2):

When I got this error with `SwiftUI` it was because I forgot to set my view's `EnvironmentObject` with `.environmentObject()`. The stated error is completely irrelevant, but making that change fixed it for me. Still a bug with Xcode 11 showing the wrong error, but potentially means there's legitimately an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, closing and opening the Xcode fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error with SwiftUI running in simulator. I solved it just by changing the region from `Setting -> General -> Language & Region -> Region` to `India`.